# How to detect bots without User Agent?

Tags: bots, detect

About 500 times a day, a bot is rendering and registering at my page. I know that it's a bot, because it has been a week with the same behaviour. 
I already using a captcha. So the user angent looks like:
`Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.59.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.9 Safari/534.59.10`
But it could also be an iPod or iPhone (it happend before).

So this User Agents aren't looking like a bot, so my question is: How can I detect that it's a bot, even if the user agent doesn't look like a bot?

Answer (score 0):

User Agent can be easily spoofed, so this is not actually the question you want answered. You want to know what is broken with your CAPTCHA implementation, or if someone can suggest a harder to crack one.

Comment: I know it can be spoofed, but what alternatives do I have to ban this bot?

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of something like `fail2ban` http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page and `modsecurity` http://www.modsecurity.org/ along with what [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/409020/john-shedletsky) suggested.

If you're running WordPress, I highly suggest using [WordFence](http://www.wordfence.com/) as well.

Comment: Thanks, I´ll have a look at the fail2ban

Comment: Ok, I had a look into fail2ban and it seems to be simple. I already have a script which detects multiple fails of forms. So is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I detect that it's a bot, even if the user agent doesn't look
>   like a bot?

Add an input field to your form with style display:none. The input field is not visible to humans so they will not enter anything, but auto-posting bots will populate the value. Pieces and parts only below (not a full example) just enough to give you the general idea.

```
$bot = ( isset( $_POST['bot'] ) ) ? $_POST['bot'] : '';    

<input type="text" name="bot" id="bot" style="display:none;" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($bot)); ?>" />

if ( $_POST['bot'] != '' ) {
    $spambot = 'Confirmed SpamBot - Bot Trap Value Entered: '.$_POST['bot'];
}
```